# How can I make sure some javascripts can be executed after Angular JS is done

Tags: angularjs

I need to execute some javascript after angular js finishes its routing and DOM rendering.

How could I do it?

Let's say I need to run OtherJavascript.js after Angular rendered its DOM and routing

```
<body ng-app="portal">
<div ng-include="'app/tpl/header.html'"></div>
<ui-view/>
<div ng-include="app/tpl/footer.html">
    <script src="dist/js/dependent.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/ng_required.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./app/js/controllers/cart_base.js"></script>
    <script src="./app/js/services/tour_package_service.js"></script>
    ....
    <script type="text/javascript" src="OtherJavascript.js"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append script tag in document body after angular does its routing and rendering.

function like :

```
 var loadScript = function () {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'path.js';
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
```

create and use this in controller.